# Ubuntu vm shows Floppy disk

Tags: virtualization, qemu, floppy

I set up a qemu virtual machine on my Ubuntu 15.04. I installed Ubuntu 15.04 in it and the virtualized Ubuntu shows a Floppy Disk.

What does it mean and how do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used QEMU, but from what I'm seeing on their documentation, it looks like it will create floppy support by default for an x86 architecture machine, even if you don't have a floppy drive in your physical machine.

VMWare and VirtualBox do the same thing. It shouldn't affect performance of the VM unless you're really worried about the VENOM vulnerability. As far as disabling it goes, it looks like the easiest way to disable the floppy drive is to use `-nodefaults` when opening QEMU.

Otherwise, you should be able to patch the VM to avoid the VENOM vulnerability, but I don't think it will disable the floppy. [Here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cve-2015-3456-patch-venom-on-debian-ubuntu-fedora-centos-rhel-linux/) a link with more information on the vulnerability.

Comment: So if qemu doesn't create anything automaticly when using `nodefaults` I have to create the needed default devices mannualy, haven't I?

Comment: -nodefaults
Don’t create default devices. Normally, QEMU sets the default devices like serial port, parallel port, virtual console, monitor device, VGA adapter, floppy and CD-ROM drive and others. The -nodefaults option will disable all those default devices.

Comment: The above is from their HTML user manual and indicates that you would have to create the defaults manually. Again, I've never used qemu, so I wouldn't know from firsthand experience.